# como agregar nuevos campos a una tabla en tiempo de ejecucion de un sistema vb.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net

de antemano gracias por leer mi pregunta.

Estoy desarrollando un sistema en VB.net y Sql Server,  me piden que agregue una parte donde terminado el sistema ellos puedan agregar un nuevo campo o eliminar uno ya existente de alguna tabla pero desde el sistema (Osea que haya un apartado para crear o eliminar un nuevo campo).

No tengo idea de como se hace o que tan dificil sea, ojala y me puedan orientar o dar un ejemplo de como se hace, o si es muy dificil decirmelo tambien.

Muchas gracias...

Comment: hola cristian empieza por estudiar, en internet hay muchos tutoriales buenos https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj943772.aspx o este otro https://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_database/adonet/article.php/c15033/A-Basic-VBNET-ADONET-Tutorial-Adding-Deleting-and-Updating.htm

Comment: Hola Ger eso se como se hace, creo que me entendiste mal, lo que quiero es que una vez ejecutado el sistema puedas agregar o eliminar campos de la tabla en tiempo de ejecucion

Comment: puedes colocar lo que haz avanzado de codigo y exponer el problema que tienes?

Comment: Y una vez que el usuario agregue un campo a una tabla, como se lo vas a mostrar? que tipo de datos va a guardar? quien va a controlar esos datos? cuales son las reglas de negocio de esos datos? creo que lo que te pidieron es para sacarse de encima al desarrollador, pero tiene mas contras que ventajas.

Comment: Concuerdo contigo gbianchi , y viendo las opiniones de diferentes personas creo que es muy desventajoso hacer eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El agregar nuevas columnas a una tabla a partir de una aplicación, no es lo recomendable, dado que a medida que crece tu aplicación (Tema de escalabilidad), será muy difícil de mantener dicha tabla.

Sin embargo, existe técnicas para mitigar dicho error, lo cual te ofreceré una de ellas.

La solución consta en realizar dos tabla, la cual en una almacena la información general del formulario y posteriormente la tabla de "metadata" almacena los campos (Inputs) con las siguientes características:

- ID_Formulario: Indica que formulario es
- Correlativo: Llave primaria auto incrementable
- Llave: Identificador único que reconoce la entrada de un formulario respectivo
- Tipo: El tipo de la llave (Entero, Booleano, Cadenas, entre otro más...)
- Valor: El valor que corresponde la llave.

En caso que deseas eliminar o agregar una nuevo campo, se debe seguir los siguientes pasos:

- **Agregar**: Solo debe agregar una nueva fila en la tabla de metadata
- **Eliminar**: Solo debe eliminar las filas, a partir de las llaves y ID_Formulario (Where ID_Formulario = {ID_FORMULARIO} AND llave = {Llave})

Te adjunto un ejemplo:

Diagrama de entidad relación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberte ayudado saludos.